# Error while input 2 strings, int and float in C from keyboard

Tags: c, input

I have some issues whith inputs from keyboard in C.
My input shoud be:

1. `string` with spaces
2. `string` with spaces
3. `int`
4. `float`

This declaration of input worked, but if first I enter `int` and `float` and then strings:

```
char  title[60], author[50];
int   year;
float rate;
char temp;
scanf("%d",  &year);
scanf("%f",  &rate)
scanf("%c",&temp);
scanf ("%[^\n]", title);
scanf("%c",&temp);
scanf ("%[^\n]", author);
```

With another order input behaves unpredictably.

I need a fast and efficient way to read inputs in the exactly order I described above.

Comment: Use a space before specifier for characters and strings to get rid of blank characters present in stdin buffer, e.g.`" %[^\n]"`

Comment: `scanf ("%[^\n]", title); scanf("%c",&temp);` is like `gets()` only worse.  Use width limits to not overrun the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` leaves a newline character (`\n`) in the buffer, for chained `scanf`s, when reading characters or strings you'll need to get rid of those, a simple solution is to add a space before the specifier, wether it's `%s`, `%c` or `%[ ]`.

For your code, mixing the `scanf`s around:

```
scanf(" %59[^\n]", title);
scanf("%f", &rate);
scanf(" %49[^\n]", author);
scanf("%d", &year);
```

This should parse all your inputs correctly. As would any other reordering, provided that you then input the values in the correct order.

<kbd>[**Live demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7LvM805ZmRkwPyPa)</kbd>

I added size limits to the strings in `scanf`, you should always do this to avoid buffer overflow.

Verifying the return values of `scanf` is also advised to make sure the inputs were read correctly, *e.g.*:

```
if(scanf(" %59[^\n]", title) == 1){
    //Ok
}
else{
    //Deal with bad input
}
```

Note that if you want a more robust way to parse inputs that allow you to perform complete input checks, you shoud use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) generally and then [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) / [`strtof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/) to parse the numerical inputs.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I don't see it, what do you mean? See the link.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, well spotted, didn't realize that the OP was using temp to discard characters. Also are you sure that atoi is the way to go? int overflow will cause UB.

Comment: As OP has "I need a fast and efficient way", I doubt there is the proper interest in good error handling like overflow, early end-of-file, file input error, excessive long line, non-numeric input, [the usual suspects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtSmfws0_To).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, you're probably right, i's enough for the purpose, in that case, +1.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, great share btw :)

Answer (score 2):

> With another order input behaves unpredictably.

This is due to the left-over `'\n'` after reading a number.

---

Rather than patch broken `scanf()`, read a *line* of user input with `fgets()` and then parse.

Easy and simply to re-order parsing as needed.

```
char buffer[100] = { 0 };
char title[60] = { 0 };
char author[50] = { 0 };
int   year;
float rate;

fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
year = atoi(buffer);
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
rate = atof(buffer);
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
sscanf(buffer, "%59[^\n]", title);
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
sscanf(buffer, "%49[^\n]", author);
```

Robust code would employ checks of `fgets()`, `sscanf()`, long lines and use `strtol()` and `strtof()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", title);
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", author);
scanf("%d",  &year);
scanf("%f",  &rate);
```

with this %*c, it reads newline character and here used * indicates that this newline character is discarded.
it works fine.

Comment: `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", title);` worse than `gets()`. Consider `scanf ("%59[^\n]%*c", title);`

Comment: As OP wants to re-order things, consider consuming the trailing `'\n'` of `year, rate` too.